Handling Concurrent Requests and Rollbacks in a Microservices Architecture using saga
How should we handle the following scenario? Let’s say we have three microservices. We receive two concurrent requests that update the same records in these microservices. The first request successfully executes and persists in Microservices 1 and 2, but encounters an issue in Microservice 3. Simultaneously, the second request updates the same record in Microservices 1, 2, and 3. Now, Microservice 1 publishes a compensate message to roll back the first request in Microservices 1 and 2. However, during this time, the record in Microservices 1 and 2 has already been updated by the second request. How can we roll back the updated record in Microservices 1 and 2?

Make sure that the records that share the same business ID are not updated concurrently. Serialize the updates using some orchestrator like temporal.io. It allows executing (and rolling back if needed) the first update and only then starting the second one.
